# how to run the bytecode generated by ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to the Ruby scripting language.

I was learning how to generate the byte code in Ruby.
I found the answer for generating the byte code.

But I don't know how to run that generated byte code. I searched the internet, but I didn't get the answer for this.

Generating a byte code:-

```
puts RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("x = 50; x > 100 ? 'foo' : 'bar'").disassemble
```

The output is,

```
== disasm: <RubyVM::InstructionSequence:<compiled>@<compiled>>==========
local table (size: 2, argc: 0 [opts: 0, rest: -1, post: 0, block: -1] s1)
[ 2] x          
0000 trace            1                                               (   1)
0002 putobject        50
0004 setlocal         x
0006 trace            1
0008 getlocal         x
0010 putobject        100
0012 opt_gt           <ic:1>
0014 branchunless     20
0016 putstring        "foo"
0018 leave            
0019 pop              
0020 putstring        "bar"
0022 leave
```

I don't know how to execute the same script, by using the generated byte code.

Anyone please explain me how to execute this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR;** You are looking for [`.eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html#method-i-eval) method.

The `.compile` method would return an instance of `RubyVM::InstructionSequence` class, which has `.eval` method that evaluates/runs your "compiled" instructions.

```
iseq = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("x = 50; x > 100 ? 'foo' : 'bar'")    
iseq.eval       # => "bar"
```

Or, a oneliner:

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile("x = 50; x > 100 ? 'foo' : 'bar'").eval
```

Comment: One can't run the output of `.disassemble`, though. :)

Comment: Is any other way to run this. For example, copying the code return by the .compile and execute that with any other external command ? Is it possible?

Comment: @suresh: that's a totally different requirement (the external tool). Do you want to run the thing or not?

Comment: @suresh: also, if you're new to ruby, this is __not__ what you should be focusing on. Focus on learning ruby instead.

Comment: Actually this is my assignment question. I need to get the byte code for a simple script and store it in another file, after that run that file using ruby or external command ?

Comment: @suresh: this answer shows you how to run bytecode using ruby. You just have to figure out how to write and read a file.

Comment: I was tried, but if I did like this, the class name for that is only in string. I don't know how to convert class string to the class RubyVM::InstructionSequence ?

Answer (score 0):

rbc

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

byte_code = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_file ARGV[0]
File.open(ARGV[1], 'w') do |f|
  f.write <<~RUBY
            #!/usr/bin/env ruby

            RubyVM::InstructionSequence.load_from_binary(DATA.read).eval

            __END__
          RUBY
end
File.open(ARGV[1], 'ab') { |f| f.write byte_code.to_binary }

# or FileUtils.chmod('+x', ARGV[1]), if you don't mind requiring 'fileutils'
File.chmod(0775, ARGV[1])
```

hello.rb

```
puts 'Hello world'
```

run

```
$ ./rbc hello.rb hello && ./hello
Hello world
```

Note that it won't work well for multiple files